# SSRS dynamic chart width, but keep margins static width

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a chart with an expression to set the width based on the number of months in the dataset.

However the wider the chart, the greater the margin size.

This is stopping me aligning it with a matrix that sits underneath...

**How can I fix the margin width?**

[image]

**EDIT**

Chart's DynamicWidth expression as requested:

```
=IIF( 
    Count(Fields!Month_Of_Year.Value) < 12,
    1.38 * 12 & " cm",
    (Count(Fields!Month_Of_Year.Value) * 1.38) & " cm"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope this will answer you question :

1. Select the Chart and in the Properties window(the one on right side) click the (...)button for the property **ChartAreas**
2. Position -> Expand the property CustomPosition and change **Enabled to True and set the property Left to 0**

This will make the chart area move to the left Permanently.

otherwise I can provide more workarounds if this

Comment: I can see it having some effect but it's not behaving as expected. I'd probably need to modify my DynamicWidth expression and also add a CustonPosition->Width expression. Overkill and time-consuming. Users may have to live with it as it is unless there's an easier solution.

Comment: Try this one it might work for u                                                                          1． Right-click the chart, choose Properties,
2． On the Properties dialog, click the X Axis tab,
3． Check the Side Margins checkbox.